# При асинхронном парсинге openweathermap последний запрос сессий долго грузится

Tags: python, парсер

При асинхронном parsing openweathermap одни запросы долго грузится, а другие быстро .

````
async def Parser_Yandex_Weather(session, coord, header, url, source, name_sity, function):
    global TIME_COUNT
    time_start = time()
    async with session.get(url.format(coord[0], coord[1]), proxy=None, headers=header) as response:
        
        print(str(TIME_COUNT))
        print(f"{str(time_start - time())} - {source}")
        TIME_COUNT += 1     

async def Start_Parser(coordinates, name_sity, deskriptor):

    weather_task = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for num, coord in enumerate(coordinates):
            weather_task.append(asyncio.create_task(Parser_Yandex_Weather(session, coord, header=None, url=URLS[1], source=SOURSE[1], name_sity=None, function=deskriptor)))
        await asyncio.gather(*weather_task)

for i in range(10):
    asyncio.run(Start_Parser([[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], [None, None], get_data_parser))
    print('\n')```

Вывод консоли:
```0
-0.8361387252807617 - OpenWeather api
1
-36.48248291015625 - OpenWeather api
2
-69.45277571678162 - OpenWeather api


3
-0.7874956130981445 - OpenWeather api
4
-34.47717308998108 - OpenWeather api
5
-36.972941875457764 - OpenWeather api


6
-0.7624316215515137 - OpenWeather api
7
-0.7675058841705322 - OpenWeather api
8
-0.8083162307739258 - OpenWeather api```
````

Comment: при парсинге yandex api все запросы грузятся одинаково быстро